# How can i differentiate a productpage from a category page?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, routes

So I'm working on a little project to build a webshop.
But I'm really struggeling with working out this part of the routing.

This is my routing code:

```
 { path: 'productrange', component: ProductRangeComponent },
 { path: 'productrange/:productgroup', component: ProductRangeComponent },
 { path: 'productrange/:productgroup/:producttype', component: ProductRangeComponent },
 { path: 'products/:productgroup/:producttype', component: ProductsComponent },
 { path: 'products/:productgroup/:producttype/:productsubtype', component: ProductsComponent },
```

So this works but i think this is not the best way to do it. As i'm using two different components and two different paths.

This is what i would like it to be:

```
 { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
 { path: 'products/:productgroup', component: ProductsComponent },
 { path: 'products/:productgroup/:producttype', component: ProductsComponent },
 { path: 'products/:productgroup/:producttype/:productsubtype', component: ProductsComponent },
```

This would work as long as the products are only begin displayed in the last path, but this is not always the case. Sometimes there can be products in the 3rd path or even the 2nd path. But I have no idea how to let the system know  that there should be products displaying.

Ofcourse i could just make multiple calls to the database checking if there are more categories and if not search for products and go from there. But I don't believe this is the right way because that would mean unnecessary calls towards server and database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add child routes.

```
{ path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, children: [
   { path: ':productgroup', component: ProductRangeComponent }
  ]
}
```

see also https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looks very promising but i have one issue. A child route requires me to have the product page inside of the productrange component. I want them to have their own page while still maintaining the routing. To be more clear: -ProductsComponent contains a list of products. -ProductRangeComponent contains a list of groups of products(so computers/laptops/tablets), it doesn't include the actual list of products.